# uncheck hidden inputs jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to uncheck an `input` item within each list item, where the `li` is currently `checked` and `hidden`.

DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/VHW9U/

```
$('#mylist input:checked').each(function() {
    if(!$(this).is(":visible")){
        $(this).find("input:checkbox").prop("checked", false);
    }
});
```

The above code does not work, i have tried various different approaches and none of them seem to work. If you view the source code of the jsfiddle you will see that the hidden `inputs` are still `checked`

Comment: `$('#mylist li:hidden input:checked").prop("checked", false);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, the checkboxes aren't inside checkboxes. `$(this).find("input:checkbox")`. `this`is the checkbox

```
$('#mylist input:checked').each(function() {
    if(!$(this).is(":visible")){
        $(this).prop("checked", false);
    }
});
```

**Note** This will not change the attribute checked, but the property. [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Alfie/VHW9U/1/)

Comment: Thanks, this works. Will it be classed as `checked` on form submission?

Comment: @AlwaysLearning It depends on how you are validating the checkboxes on the form submission. If you search for the checkboxes like this `input:checked` it will not be classed as checked.

Answer (score 1):

Try

<kbd>[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/AkSNL/)</kbd>

```
$('#mylist li:hidden input:checked').prop("checked", false);
```

---

`$('#mylist li:hidden input:checked')` get `checked`  `input` inside the hidden `li` which  inside element with id `mylist`

---

Or

<kbd>[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/AkSNL/)</kbd>

```
$('#mylist input:checked:hidden').prop("checked", false);
```

`$('#mylist input:checked:hidden')`  get `checked`  `input` inside element with id `mylist`

Comment: Thanks, but if you check the source code it still display the hidden elements as `checked`?

Comment: @AlwaysLearning Un-hide the `li` element you will see the magic --> see demo --> http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/AkSNL/1/